# High Charts - Stacked Bar chart With Data from Database

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am new to this Highcharts. Can Some one please help me how to create a stacked column chart with data from database? I looked at samples all over the internet and everything is written using static data. Can some one please help?

How to Get series and x-axis categories from database?

Comment: yes using ajax loaded data you can do it.

First get the data from server using an ajax call and then use it in the chart to build it

Answer (score 0):

you can get the data required to load the chart from server using an ajax call. in server you can run some db query to fetch the data.

[here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/1q0ky4go/)  which tells you how you can use ajax loaded data with highchars.

reference for ajax calls : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Here in the code getJSON is used.

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=analytics.csv&callback=?', function (data){
// here you can have you code that handles the data
}
```

here we are getting the data that is present in a csv file in the required format